# Good way to define module in Spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, module, tiles

Im using Spring mvc 3.1 version and Apache Tiles 2.2.2 version i'd like to define some common modules in my applications pages.
For example i want to define a menu in the top, a left side and right side,.. all my page will display these block. 
Im using Tiles to define the differents blocks, some part of tiles implements ViewPreparer because i need to get information from database, know if the user is logged,... each tile is responsable of its own module(get data, set attribute for the jsp...).

Is it a good way to create some modules ? Or should i define a controller who will define the data, the business...to all page modules ? (left side, right side, menu...)

Answer (score 0):

If your common module only consists of HTML then it doesn't matter how you do it. Tiles template is sufficient.

The problem is if the common module need models to be populated on the controller. You don't want to duplicate the code on every single of your controller which view includes the common module.

One approach you can take is subclass your controller with a class that populates common module model, eg:

```
public class CommonHandler {

  @ModelAttribute("loggedInUser")
  public UserInfo getLoggedInUser() {
    // check and return logged in user if any here..
  }

}

@Controller
public class MyController extends CommonHandler (

  @RequestMapping(..)
  public String myHandler() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

In above example if `myHandler` is requested, `getLoggedInUser` from `CommonHandler` class will automatically be called to populate `loggedInUser` model. In your view you just obtain it using `${loggedInUser}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer gerrytan. Should i only write html in Tile ? If my tile implements ViewPreparer i can communicate with service from tile and get more informations. I'd like to keep module independent from other controllers, if all my controller extends commonHandler all my module are coupled to the controller. Do you think its a better to define the module in Controller which extendscommonHandler or in ViewPreparer ?

Comment: Using controller you can get Spring dependency injection, AOP etc. Not familiar about ViewPreparer.

Comment: I tried with ViewPreparer and it works like a controller (for dependency injection...)

Answer (score 0):

When using ViewPreparerSupport  which implements ViewPreparer, it works very well :

```
@Component
public class MyPreparer extends ViewPreparerSupport {

        @Autowired
        private UtilisateurService utilisateurService;

        @Override
        public void execute(TilesRequestContext tilesContext,
                        AttributeContext attributeContext) {
                //information to set for the jsp tile
        }


}
```